# Add classes to the menu item <li>?

Tags: 8, navigation

In `hook_preprocess_menu()`, I want to add custom classes to the `<li>` tag.

I tried the following lines of code, one at a time.

- `$item['attributes']->addClass('section');`
- `$item['attributes']->setAttribute('class', array('section'));`
- `$item['attributes']->setAttribute('class', 'section');`

In any case, this is the HTML markup I get.

```html
<li class="Array class">
```

How do I add the desired classes?

Comment: Did you try just adding it in the menu twig file first?

Comment: Have you also tried `$item['attributes']['class'][] = 'section';`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your theme extends Classy, you can add a `menu.html.twig` file in your theme to override the menu twig used:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21classy%21templates%21navigation%21menu.html.twig/8.6.x

This block here:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'menu-item',
    item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
    item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
    item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
  ]
%}
```

Simply add a new line:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'menu-item',
    item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
    item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
    item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
    'section'
  ]
%}
```

If your theme does not use Classy as a base, then you have to refer to the Stable theme twig file which does not do this:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21stable%21templates%21navigation%21menu.html.twig/8.6.x

In this case, you would have to add the `set` block within the `for item in items` loop just like the Classy file does, and add `addClass(classes)` method on the `li` item:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'menu-item',
    item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
    item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
    item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
    'section'
  ]
%}
<li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

This will add the 'section' class on every single `li` in the menu though, so, if you only want it to apply to the top level menu items for example, you could do:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'menu-item',
    item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
    item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
    item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
    menu_level == 0 ? 'section'
  ]
%}
```

Additionally, if you only want this to apply to a *particular* menu and not all menus, then your Twig file needs to be named `menu--MENU_NAME.html.twig`. Clear caches to see any changes.