# How to add separate class to menu link using hook

Tags: 8, theming

I want to add custom classes to the anchor tag in the main menu.

[image]

I implemented `hook_preprocess_menu()`, but it assigned the classes to the `<ul>` tag and I want to add the classes to the `<a>` tag.

The code I am using is the following one.

```
function menu_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['menu_name'] == 'main') {
    if (!isset($variables['attributes']['class'])) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'] = [];
    }
    $data = \Drupal::state()->get('my_data', 'bar');
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Unfortunately we don't know what you've tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck right now. Therefore we can't tell you what's maybe wrong with you current approach. Please update your question to share your current approach with us. Many thanks.

Comment: i think its clear. updated

Comment: [Add classes to the menu item <li>?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274500/add-classes-to-the-menu-item-li)

Comment: still not working . see code

Comment: And the other answer from the linked question? In the template? The question actually got hold of `$item` first.

Comment: i think, attributes is index with `#`. `$variables['#attributes']['class][] = 'your-class'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your class in a variable out attributes:

```
function menu_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['menu_name'] == 'main') {
    $variables['my_magic_class'] = 'my-class';
  }
}
```

Now you have to override menu.html.twig template into your theme template folder

```
...
<a class="menu-item {{ my_magic_class }}" OTHER_LINK_ATTRIBUTES>LINK_TEXT</a>
...
```